# How to stop mysqld process?

Tags: 14.04, mysql, process

result of `ps -e | grep mysqld`

[image]

running `htop` and clicking on memory usage..

[image]

It is taking 33% of 4gb memory.

I just want to end the mysqld process.. running `sudo pkill mysqld` ends the process but again the process starts.. I want to completely end it and get the memory back.

Comment: Press f5 in htop to see what process is starting mysqld

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `mysql` Upstart configuration has the [`respawn`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn) option:

```
$ grep respawn /etc/init/mysql.conf
respawn
respawn limit 2 5
        elif echo $statusnow | grep -q 'respawn/' ; then
```

The `respawn` option tells Upstart to restart the process if it exits or is killed.
The limit is 2, so you can try killing of the processes twice, which will tell Upstart not to start them again, or use:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Comment: `mysql stop` stops it, and yet it still starts again and again... I commented out respawn rows in the configuration, but that didn't help.

Comment: @Janis if `service mysql stops` mysql, and then it restarts, then something else is starting it. Look for cronjobs or monitoring scripts or something.

Comment: Thanks! I did the stopping by `/etc/init.d/mysql stop`, but it turned out that I had to run `service mysql stop` instead. I thought that they are the same (one calling the other or both calling the same command).

Answer (score 18):

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
service mysql stop
killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
```

When you see the following information, you success

```
mysql: no process found
mysqld_safe: no process found
mysqld: no process found
```

I use this to solve the installation problem of MySQL 5.6 in Ubuntu 15.10 using this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/).

During this installation, I encounter the problem saying:

```
mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
```

Just completely stop the mysqld, mysqld_safe, mysql solves the problem

Answer (score 5):

Run `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot find mysql within `/etc/init` or `/etc/init.d`, check that id did not come together with another package.
As for me, i found out that my mysqld runs to support nextcloud, i did

```
$> find '/etc' | grep 'mysql'

/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap.nextcloud.mysql.service
/etc/systemd/system/snap.nextcloud.mysql.service
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mys
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow all the answers couldn't help me until I first restarted the server then stopped it, so here are the steps:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart

sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

This worked in Ubuntu WSL.

Comment: duplicate of this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/771591/790920

Comment: @abu_bua I tried the steps he put there and it still didn't work for me until I restarted and then stropped, that's why I have it specific steps in that order if anyone has same problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck in a running commang inside the console, you can try one of the following.

- Ctrl + c
- Ctrl + q
- F10
- type "exit" + Enter
- Esc

Answer (score 0):

`System Preferences -> MySql -> Stop MySQL Server`

This is the only one that worked for me, stopping / killing it from the command line would always let it restart.