Mysql wont start
I restarted the mysql service then this happens when I check the status:
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-09-25 20:22:27 PST; 18min ago
    Process: 849199 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 849238 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1>
        CPU: 143ms

Sep 25 20:22:27 CADI-SERVER systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Sep 25 20:22:27 CADI-SERVER systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Sep 25 20:22:27 CADI-SERVER systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 25 20:22:27 CADI-SERVER systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 25 20:22:27 CADI-SERVER systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.


Does this help at all? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185783/how-fix-permanently-job-for-mysql-service-failed-because-the-control-process-ex

Please update your question with more details. What is your Ubuntu version? What is your MySQL version. How have you installed it? Sharing some logs will help too.
